# Tally elements in a list of matrices up to an overall sign

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix

I have a list of matrices like the following one with 6 elements:

```
lst = {{{(2 I)/3, 0}, {0, -((2 I)/3)}}, {{0, -(2/3)}, {2/3, 0}}, 
       {{-((2 I)/3), 0}, {0, (2 I)/3}}, {{0, (2 I)/3}, {(2 I)/3, 0}}, 
       {{0, 2/3}, {-(2/3), 0}}, {{0, -((2 I)/3)}, {-((2 I)/3), 0}}};
```

and I would like to look for duplicates up to an overall sign.

```
MatrixForm /@ lst
```

[image]

Then, I would like to keep only one instance of each pair in the list with a constant factor that counts the elements. In other words, I would like to obtain a resulting list like

```
 res = {2{{(2 I)/3, 0}, {0, -((2 I)/3)}}, 2{{0, -(2/3)}, {2/3, 0}}, 
        2{{0, (2 I)/3}, {(2 I)/3, 0}}};
```

What is an efficient way to compare elements of the `lst` up to overall signs and then construct the appropriate `res` list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using `Tally`:**

[image]

```
lst = {{{(2 I)/3, 0}, {0, -((2 I)/3)}}, {{0, -(2/3)}, {2/3, 
     0}}, {{-((2 I)/3), 0}, {0, (2 I)/3}}, {{0, (2 I)/3}, {(2 I)/3, 
     0}}, {{0, 2/3}, {-(2/3), 0}}, {{0, -((2 I)/3)}, {-((2 I)/3), 
     0}}};

Times @@@ Tally[lst, ((#1 == -#2) || (#1 == #2)) &] // Map[MatrixForm]
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this does not give the exact result that I want. For example, if the first matrix appears twice, it is not counted. But a simple solution for that is to replace your code with ````Times @@@ Tally[lst, ((#1 == -#2) || (#1 == #2)) &] // Map[MatrixForm]````

Comment: I will accept your answer though because it helped me get the correct result after a small modification. Perhaps edit your answer to reflect the correct solution?

Comment: Also, there seems to be an issue with the evaluation if the entries of the matrix include parameters without assigned values. Is there anything we can do in that case?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer. Regarding your second comment about evaluation with parameters, I think it would involve some kind of computation to ascertain equivalence. It is best to start a new question with enough test cases.

Answer (score 4):

A variant of Syed's answer

```
Transpose[{Length /@ #, #}] &@ Gather[list, #1 == -#2 || #1 == #2 &] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A variant of @eldo's answer:

```
f = Cases[#, x_ /; x != 0, {2}] &;

Times @@ {Length@#, #[[1]]} & /@ Gather[lst, f@#1 === -f@#2 &] // Map[MatrixForm]
```

[image]